# I am not receiving the signed_request parameter on my canvas page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, canvas

My application is not receiving the signed_request parameter when I load the app in the canvas. I am getting a code and state variable sent over, but the signed_request parameter is not being sent. How can I receive this parameter? My canvas page is http://apps.facebook.com/fb-minesweeper

Answer (score 0):

After i authenticate i'm being send to a site off facebook: =">http://minesweeper.andydaykin.com/?state=8b5549e7ae08812dda0354b764eff7e8&code=AQBvjmrtifvlY3XTC85sLtJJKegcTUpBd8hQC3i0Sg-1CpYpT7xXeUVfLbBxUKfv-MeEmlvp8zvBsPXio6EbXv1nG9wRqTUx_91pUSZ9vVSYGV7rIjEUU-jHTreiJbsBpTl9dQkMoX-YSte49E9LJbPGW68hpJqsCnpo0x4RprjHXYo7G5gADCgzJv1TS8ig4NU#*=*

You won't recieve a signed request here because this is not your canvas page... if you wouldn't redirect you would recieve the signed_request on http://apps.facebook.com/fb-minesweeper/ , you could add this to your redirect url...

cheers!